# What is happening in this MongoDB Query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

`{
    $or:[{TextField1:{$eq:"DX93E6XX6R"}}],
    $or:[{TextField1:{$eq:"N4JXFTNP64"}}]
}`

There are two documents in the collection.  One with a "TextField1" value equal to the first expression and one with the same field equal to the second expression.

My thought was:

`Find all documents where TextField1 equals "DDX93E6XX6R" AND TextField1 equals "N4JXFTNP64"`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a sensible query because you can't have two fields named `$or` in the same object so only the second one will be used (overwriting the first one). And an `$or` with one element is the same as just that element.

So it's the same as:

```
{TextField1:{$eq:"N4JXFTNP64"}}
```

Which is the same as:

```
{TextField1: "N4JXFTNP64"}
```

Which is:

```
Find all documents where TextField1 equals "N4JXFTNP64"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to match documents with either value, then your statement could be either:

{$or: [{Textfield1: "foo1"}, {Textfield1: "foo2"}]}

or...

{Textfield1: {$in: ["foo1", "foo2"]}}